# python - Why does the += operator with lists is able to append a string but not list = list + "stri"

Tags: python, list

```py
l = list()

l = l + "string" #throws error
l += "string" #works
```

I was just wondering why this strange behaviour since we were taught `l = l + "something"` is the same as `l += "something"`.

Comment: Well, the only sensible conclusion is: these are not the same, and someone taught you incorrectly. And in fact it is an inconsitency that `+` works with lists only while `+=` with any iterable. There's not really much more to say about it.

Comment: Look at the contents of `l` and you might get a better idea...

Comment: `l += x` is only equivalent to `l = l + x` if `l.__iadd__` is undefined or defined to be equivalent to `l.__add__`.

Comment: Your title is inaccurate. You can't append a string with `+=`; it's not the whole string that gets added to the list, but each character in the string individually.

Comment: "we were taught `l = l + "something"` is the same as `l += "something"`" you were taught incorrectly.

Answer (score 4):

`+` requires a list when adding to a list.

`+=` only requires an *iterable* when updating a list. A `str` value is (for better or worse) an iterable of single-character strings, so that

```
l += "string"
```

causes `'s'`, `'t'`, `'r'`, etc to be appended to `l`. The `+=` operator is more or less equivalent to

```
l.extend("string")
```

Comment: It's not "more or less equivalent", it's the same.

Comment: `l.extend(...)` is an expression statement which also produces the value `None`. `l += ...` is an assignment statement with no value of its own.

Comment: I *could* (though I can't imagine why I'd want to) write `print(l.extend(...))`, but `print(l += ...)` is a syntax error.

Comment: Oookay, except for those nitpicky details, they're [the same operation](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-mutable) as far as the list is concerned. ;)